# how differentiate symbolic function has a variable name matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, symbolic-math

please,

I want matlab to generate dynamic variable name as many as specified number 
ex,
generate F1,F2,...

but the problem that I want to differienate the unspeceified number
I use

```
for k = 1:number

   eval(diff(['F', num2str(k)]))

end
```

so what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should start your code with:

```
f=sym('f',[1,number])
```

this creates symbolic variables f1... organised in an array.

```
for k = 1:number

   diff(f(k))

end
```

Avoid eval whenever possible. For reasons read `doc eval`.